# Add animation when expression value changes - Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I have an expression on a page called 'pointsBalance' that displays numeric value. Its hooked up to an **observable**, and when pointsBalance value goes up, I want to change the colour to green then back to its original colour, and red if it goes down in value. I thought I could use **Angular 5** new animation aliases [:increment and :decrement](https://scotch.io/@Viclotana/whats-new-in-angular-5#toc-animations-update) but I've been having problems with it.

HTML to display the points balance:

```
<div [@valueAnimation]="pointsBalance">{{ pointsBalance }}</div>
```

Code that sets the animation and the pointsBalance observable:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, style, transition, animate, keyframes, query, 
    stagger, state, group } from '@angular/animations';
import { CompetitionsService } from "../../../shared/index";
@Component({
  selector: 'points',
  templateUrl: './...html',

  animations: [
    trigger('valueAnimation', [
      transition(':increment', group([
        query(':enter', [
          style({ color: 'green', fontSize: '50px' }),
          animate('0.8s ease-out', style('*'))
        ])
      ])),
      transition(':decrement', group([
        query(':enter', [
          style({ color: 'red', fontSize: '50px' }),
          animate('0.8s ease-out', style('*'))
        ])
      ]))
    ])
  ]
})
export class CompetitionDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  pointsBalance: number;

  constructor(private competitionsService: CompetitionsService, ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.competitionsService.updatePointsBalance$.subscribe(
      (pointsBalance) => {
        this.pointsBalance = pointsBalance;
      }
    )
  }
}
```

And when pointsBalance value changes I get this console error:

> ERROR Error: Unable to process animations due to the following failed trigger transitions
>    @valueAnimation has failed due to:
>
> - `query(":enter")` returned zero elements. (Use `query(":enter", { optional: true })` if you wish to allow this.)

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error? Or is there another way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: The error message actually offers a workaround (which is nice). Did you give that a try?

Comment: Yes I did - but the animation still didn't work.

Comment: I mean I added { optional: true } and it still didn't work

Answer (score 3):

the `:enter` animation will only animate elements that are newly created. Your "hacky" workaround works because it forces the inner span to get recreated whenever the value changes. I think what you want is to remove the `:enter` query. You want to animate when the number is in/decremented, and your animation has nothing to do with elements being added.

Comment: Hey Benjamin. Many thanks for your explanation. You are right, I want to animate as the number is in/decremented. Do you know how I can achieve this?

Comment: I think you just need to remove the enter query so it doesn't "filter" the animation to only apply to entering elements

Answer (score 2):

I found a fix from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43967392/creating-a-transition-when-changing-properties-in-angular-2-4) and [here](https://medium.com/@programadriano/angular-5-animations-increment-and-decrement-12bb6aa992eb).

```
<div [@valueAnimation]="pointsBalance"><span *ngFor="let pointsBalance of [ pointsBalance ]">{{ pointsBalance }}</span></div>
```

Feels a bit hacky though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just going to paste the code as it would look, as [Benjamin Kindle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7151388/benjamin-kindle) said, I tried it and it worked:

```
animations: [
    trigger('valueAnimation', [
      transition(':increment', [
          style({ color: 'green', fontSize: '50px' }),
          animate('0.8s ease-out', style('*'))
        ]
      ),
      transition(':decrement', [
          style({ color: 'red', fontSize: '50px' }),
          animate('0.8s ease-out', style('*'))
        ]
      )
    ])
  ]
```